# Login form not working on Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: forms, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.1

I'm having a bit of a problem with an HTML login form on Windows Mobile 6.1.  I can type in the username and password, but if I tap the login button, nothing happens.  The HTML for the opening `<form>` tag is as follows:

```
<form:form name="loginForm" class="login-form" action="loginForm"
    onsubmit="return isBlank();" commandName="validate">
```

`loginForm` refers to a Java method.  What's going wrong here, and how hard would it be to fix?

Comment: Does this work when accessed from a PC?

Comment: @josef Yes.  It does.

Comment: Is this ASP? Normally html form is <form name="loginForm" class="login-form" action="loginForm.php"
    onsubmit="return isBlank();" commandName="validate"> there is no method arg and action is normally a target URL. And Java is not JavaScript. Try that: <form name="loginForm" class="login-form" 
    onsubmit="return loginForm();">